# Texture painting showing UVGrid when coloring

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I modeled a human figure and i have UVMapped every part of it. Now i am trying to TexturePaint it but when i draw the color a UVGrid appears under the color. I would like to paint my model whithout that Grid showing. Does anyone know how to get Rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have set an UVgrid image as Brush texture.

[image]

The brush texture is color-multyplied by the brush color. If you remove the brush texture you'll be able to paint the color only.